# In C - how do I define functions with pointers as arguments?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am trying to define a function titled scanEntries which takes an int argument and a pointer argument. When i tried to compile it, I got an error message:

> ```
> "warning: passing argument 2 of ‘scanEntries’ makes pointer from integer 
>  without a cast [enabled by default]"
> ```

I tried looking up that error message here, but all I got was results about existing string-related functions, not customized functions. I've never tried writing functions with pointers as arguments before; what am I doing wrong? What exactly needs to be casted here and how do I do it?

```
 /* function to scan any integer value */
int scanInt() {
    int output;
    scanf("%d\n", output);
    return(output);
}

/* scanInt but as one entry out of a group */
int scanEntry(int number, int total) {
    printf("Please enter score %d of %d: ", number+1, total);
    return(scanInt());
}

/* scanEntry for an entire dynamic array) */
void scanEntries(int total, int *p) {
    int number;
    for(number = 0; number < total; number++) {
        *(p + number) = scanEntry(number, total);
        /* for testing */
        printf("%d", *(p + number));
    }
}
```

Here is where scanEntries is called, plus one more function not shown above that I used here:

```
/* scanInt but with a prompt to enter size */
int enterSize() {
    printf("Please enter size of array: ");
    return(scanInt());
}

int main() {
    /* entering initial size, done in a separate function */
    int initSize = enterSize();
    int *p; /* p is an int pointer */
    p = calloc(initSize, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d", initSize);

    scanEntries(enterSize(), *p);
}
```

Comment: can you show us the scanEntries call ?

Comment: This code does not constitute a [mcve] since the function you're asking about (`scanEntries`) is not called

Comment: If you declare `int *p;` and your prototype is `void scanEntries(int total, int *p)`, you simply call it as `scanEntries(enterSize(), p);` (no `'*'` here) `"warning: passing argument 2 of ‘scanEntries’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]"` is due to your attempt to pass `*p` which dereferences the integer pointer `'p'` resulting in an `int` value instead of pointer to `int`.

Comment: `*(p + number)` and alike should be written as `p[number]`

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic gist on how to :

- Declare a function that accepts a pointer
- Pass a pointer to a function

Minimal Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementMyInt(int *p) {
  // increment the value of the int that p points to
  (*p)++;
}

int main() {
  int n1 = 3;
  int *n2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *n2 = 7;
  incrementMyInt(&n1); // pass the address of n
  incrementMyInt(n2);
  printf("n1 is %d\n", n);
  printf("n2 is %d\n", *n2);
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs `n1 is 4` and `n2 is 8`.

Comment: He can do it just the way he is attempting with the allocated pointer `p`. Your example is for a different case of passing the ***address of*** an `int` as a pointer.

Comment: Ah, correct! :) When I answered the question was not well-specified so I just answered what was on the title.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
scanEntries(enterSize(), *p);
```

To:

```
scanEntries(enterSize(), p);
```

## Explanation

You have to pass a pointer as the second parameter of the function. p is a pointer to an int, thus, the call you made is passing the int instead of the pointer. That's why you have the warning.

Comment: Your statement is not incorrect, but it should be `scanEntries (initSize, p);` otherwise the program will block waiting on duplicate input. (you already called `enterSize()` here `int initSize = enterSize();`.)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of your function is fine.  The problem is how you're calling it.

In your `main` function, you declare `p` as a pointer:

```
int *p; /* p is an int pointer */
```

But then you dereference that pointer when calling `scanEntries`:

```
scanEntries(enterSize(), *p);
```

You're actually passing an `int` to the function instead of a pointer to `int`, so the compiler is attempting to convert the `int` into a pointer to match the parameter.  That's what the warning is telling you.

Since the function expects an `int *`, just pass it directly to the function.  Also, you don't need to call `enterSize` again here since you already got the size.  use `initSize` instead:

```
scanEntries(initSize, p);
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
scanf("%d\n", output);
```

The `%d` format specifier expects a pointer to `int`, but you're just passing a plain `int`.  Using the wrong type for a format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want to pass the address of `output` to the function, that way it gets updated.  Also, the `\n` in the format will cause your program to prompt for extra input.  It's not needed.

```
scanf("%d", &output);
```

Comment: I simply changed *p to p just now and all the errors when compiling are gone!

But when I run the program, after I enter the size of an array the program says "Segmentation fault" and terminates.

Comment: Oh Christ, I always make this mistake in scanf functions!!! Thanks so much, that should've been obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments - If you declare int `*p`; and your prototype is `void scanEntries(int total, int *p)`, you simply call it as `scanEntries(initSize, p);` (no `'*'` here) `"warning: passing argument 2 of ‘scanEntries’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]"` is due to your attempt to pass `*p` which dereferences the integer pointer `'p'` resulting in an `int` value instead of a *pointer to int*.

Beyond your initial pointer passing problem, you have a large number of additonal errors:

In  `main()` you should not call `enterSize()` a second time, instead:

```
    scanEntries (initSize, p);
```

Further, you must validate *EVERY* allocation and *EVERY* input, e.g.

```
    p = calloc(initSize, sizeof(int));
    if (!p) {   /* VALIDATE EVERY ALLOCATION */
        perror ("calloc-p");
        return 1;
    }
```

and finally, if you allocate memory, develop good habits and ensure you `free` it when it is no longer needed, e.g.

```
    free (p);   /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

In `scanInt()`, you must provide a pointer to `output` to `scanf`, e.g.

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &output) != 1) { /* VALIDATE EVERY INPUT */
        fputs ("error: invalid input - not an integer.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

(**note:** the `&output` in the `scanf` call)

Further, while equivalent, don't use pointer notation for `*(p + number)`, instead simply use `p[number]` it is more readable.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* function to scan any integer value */
int scanInt (void)
{
    int output;

    if (scanf ("%d", &output) != 1) { /* VALIDATE EVERY INPUT */
        fputs ("error: invalid input - not an integer.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (output);
}

/* scanInt but as one entry out of a group */
int scanEntry (int number, int total)
{
    printf ("Please enter score %d of %d: ", number+1, total);

    return (scanInt());
}

/* scanEntry for an entire dynamic array) */
void scanEntries (int total, int *p)
{
    int number;

    for (number = 0; number < total; number++) {
        p[number] = scanEntry (number, total);
#ifdef TESTING
        printf (" scanEntries testing - %d\n", p[number]);
#endif
    }
}

/* scanInt but with a prompt to enter size */
int enterSize (void)
{
    printf ("Please enter size of array: ");
    return (scanInt());
}

int main (void) {

    /* entering initial size, done in a separate function */
    int initSize = enterSize(),
        *p;                             /* p is an int pointer */
    p = calloc(initSize, sizeof(int));
    if (!p) {   /* VALIDATE EVERY ALLOCATION */
        perror ("calloc-p");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("%d\n", initSize);

    scanEntries (initSize, p);

    printf ("%d entries read:\n\n", initSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < initSize; i++)
        printf ("p[%2d] : %d\n", i, p[i]);

    free (p);   /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

(**note:** you can add `-DTESTING` to your compiler options to define `TESTING` to activate the additional code.)

```
$ ./bin/scanentries
Please enter size of array: 4
4
Please enter score 1 of 4: 1
Please enter score 2 of 4: 2
Please enter score 3 of 4: 3
Please enter score 4 of 4: 4
4 entries read:

p[ 0] : 1
p[ 1] : 2
p[ 2] : 3
p[ 3] : 4
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/scanentries
==11795== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11795== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11795== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11795== Command: ./bin/scanentries
==11795==
Please enter size of array: 4
4
Please enter score 1 of 4: 1
Please enter score 2 of 4: 2
Please enter score 3 of 4: 3
Please enter score 4 of 4: 4
4 entries read:

p[ 0] : 1
p[ 1] : 2
p[ 2] : 3
p[ 3] : 4
==11795==
==11795== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11795==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11795==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 16 bytes allocated
==11795==
==11795== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11795==
==11795== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11795== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.